# Is this presentation of the Random real forcing separative and $\sigma$-linked?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Random real forcing is the poset formed by the closed subsets of $[0,1]$ that are non-null (with respect to the Lebesgue measure), ordered by $\subseteq$.

1. Is the Random real forcing $\sigma$-linked?
2. Is the Random real forcing non-separative?

Comment: Although we see lots of typos on this site (and I've contributed some myself), it's unusual for both of the first two words in a question to be misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.  Use the Lebesgue density theorem to find, for each condition $p$, an interval $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints such that the intersection $p\cap(a,b)$ has more than half of the measure of $(a,b)$.
2. Yes. Consider two conditions that differ by a set of measure $0$, for example $[0,\frac12]$ and $[0,\frac12]\cup\{\frac34\}$.